# Flurry Interstitial Ads not full screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, flurry

I am trying to launch a Flurry Interstitial Ad, but the ad always shows up half the screen size and the remainder is cut out..I am including the source and a screenshot below:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    searching = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
    internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [internetReachable startNotifier];
    [FlurryAds setAdDelegate:self];
    // We will show banner and interstitial integrations here.
        if ([PCFInAppPurchases boughtRemoveAds] == NO)  {
        if (![FlurryAds adReadyForSpace:@"Full Ad"]) [FlurryAds fetchAdForSpace:@"Full Ad" frame:self.view.frame size:FULLSCREEN];
        self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 50;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }else{
        self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 10;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

-(void)someMethod {
//when I display it in some method
    if ([PCFInAppPurchases boughtRemoveAds] == NO) {
        if ([FlurryAds adReadyForSpace:@"Full Ad"]) {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
        [self.view setHidden:YES];
        [FlurryAds displayAdForSpace:@"Full Ad" onView:self.view];
    }
}
```

[image: Img1]

[image: IMG2]

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details on Flurry SDK version, device name and OS, and send them across to support@flurry.com? (Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)